# R: Weird pdf of a quadratic function of a N(0,1) variable: miscoding or big rounding error?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, rounding-error, chi-squared

I would like to calculate the pdf of a random variable y defined by :

```
y=c+b*x+a*x^2
```

The pdf is a non-central chi-squared distribution. For a>0, it should be equal to zero if y is smaller than d, where d=c-(b^2)/4a.

Strangely enough, when computing it with R, the pdf shoots up at y>d+e, where e is quite large.

Is there an error in my codes (below) or is it a rounding error? In the latter case, how to address it?

```
set.seed(101)       
x <- seq(-3.5,3.5,length.out=1000)  
c<-80   
b<-30   
a<-6    
y<-c+b*x+a*(x^2) # g(x) 
## min(y)
```

Graph 1: just to get an idea of the function

```
plot(x[order(x)],y[order(x)],   
type="l",lwd=2, xlim=c(-4,4),   
ylab="y",xlab="x",  
main="a. y=g(x)and density of x")   
par(new=T)  
fx<-exp(-0.5*(x^2))/sqrt(2*pi)  
fx<-dnorm(x)    
plot(x[order(x)],fx[order(x)],yaxt="n",xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",type="l",lty=2,col="grey")  
axis(4) 
mtext(side=4,"Density",line=2)  
legend("topleft",c("y", "x density"),   
col=c("black","grey"), lty=1:2, lwd=c(1,2), bty="n")
```

PDF via method change of variables

```
g1.c<-(-b+sqrt((b^2)-4*a*(c-y)))/(2*a)  
g2.c<-(-b-sqrt((b^2)-4*a*(c-y)))/(2*a)  
g1.prime.c<-abs(1/sqrt((b^2)-4*a*(c-y)))    
fy<-dnorm(g1.c)*abs(g1.prime.c)+    
dnorm(g2.c)*abs(g1.prime.c) 
min(y)  
d<-c+(-(b^2)/(4*a)) 
plot(y,fy,type="l",lwd=2,ylab="density of y",xlab="y", ylim=c(0,0.015), 
main="y=80+30x+6x^2")   
lines(c(44.4,44.4),c(-1,0.01),lty=2)    
lines(c(d,d),c(-1,max(fy)),lty=2,col="red") 
legend("topright", c("d=42.5","d+e=44.4"),lty=2,col=c("red","black"))
```

See how it shoots up??

PDF via CDF

```
d<-c+(-(b^2)/(4*a)) 
first<- 1/(2*sqrt(a)*sqrt(y-d)) 
in_a1<-sqrt(y-d)/sqrt(a)    
in_a2<--sqrt(y-d)/sqrt(a)   
in_b<-b/(2*a)   
A<-in_a1-in_b   
B<-in_a2-in_b   
d   
min(y)  
fy_cdf<-first*(dnorm(A)+dnorm(B))   
plot(y,fy_cdf,type="l",lwd=2,ylab="density of y",xlab="y", ylim=c(0,0.015), 
main="y=80+30x+6x^2")   
lines(c(44.4,44.4),c(-1,0.01),lty=2)    
lines(c(d,d),c(-1,max(fy)),lty=2,col="red") 
legend("topright", c("d=42.5","d+e=44.4"),lty=2,col=c("red","black"))
```

Results are the same whatever methods is used to derive the pdf

```
# library("miscTools")  
# compPlot(fy_cdf,fy)   
# diff<-fy_cdf-fy   
# summary(abs(diff)) # these are minor rounding errors, 
# no issue with that.
```

Comment: Sorry wanted to start with a hello, but I don't know why, my edits are not saved.

Comment: The `{}` icon will enclose selected text in a code block,, so you don't need all those back-ticks. I suggest you edit this post to do that.

Comment: probably because I was editing at the time.  "Hello/thank you" etc. are not encouraged anyway.

Comment: Greetings are deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty experiment suggests that it's real:

```
set.seed(101)
x2 <- rnorm(200000)
c <- 80; b<-30; a<-6
y <- c+b*x2+a*(x2^2)
par(las=1)
hist(y,breaks=500,col="gray",border=NA)
```

[image]

Whether you see the very thin spike or not will depend a bit on your graphics resolution. Zoom in on left tail:

```
hist(y[y<50],breaks=500,col="gray",border=NA)
```

[image]

The folks on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) might be interested in commenting on why this PDF diverges this way at the left edge.

Comment: OK, I posted on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Yes, the last resort would be either using the hist() or the density() functions. But it annoys me to do something different in R than written in the paper, and I need to compute several statistics with the pdf such as the probability mass and the partial below mean given target levels. Also, x will be interacted with other variables so that the analytical expression for central moments will become messy, better if I get a clean pdf function from which I can derive these various statistics.

Comment: Lower mean (not below mean), sorry. And yes, better if I get a clean pdf function to generate artificial sample from which I can derive these various statistics.